# How does the multiple background images overlay each other ?Do they really overlay each other in order as they are defined?

Tags: html, css

here is the code as one image is png without any background and one is with background so i want to know how the images overlay each other? How will i know which images will going to overlay and which will lay underneath?will the first background will be only visible if i have it as an JPEG image?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#example1 {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ark1Z.gif), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG4vz.gif);
    background-position: right bottom, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Multiple Backgrounds</h1>
<p>The following div element has two background images:</p>

<div id="example1">
<h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
<p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The background images are drawn on stacking context layers on top of
>   each other. The first layer specified is drawn as if it is closest to
>   the user.

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)